# Generating a prime ideal of a polynomial ring using polynomials that involve few variables after a change of variables

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A=\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$. For $f\in A$, let $v(f)$ be the smallest $t$ such that there are $y_1,\dotsc,y_t$, where each $y_i$ is a linear combination (over $\mathbb{C}$) of $x_1,\dotsc,x_n$, and $f$ is a polynomial in $y_1,\dotsc,y_t$.

Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $A$. Let $S$ be the set of all elements $f$ of $\mathfrak{p}$ such that $v(f)\leq \dim A/\mathfrak{p} + 1$ (here $\dim$ is the Krull dimension).

> Does $S$ generate $\mathfrak{p}$?

This certainly holds if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a maximal ideal, and if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a principal prime ideal. I suspect this might work in the general case.

Comment: I can't find a paper with readymade examples of e.g. prime ideals of the ring of three variables that are not just principal, hopefully there are such papers out there so that if the conjecture is already false there you can find out just like that

Comment: @ChrisSanders: I don't quite understand what kind of example you are looking for. I understand that you are looking $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,x_3]$, but what does "not just principal" mean?

Comment: Prime ideals that are not principal, because principal is the easy case. My guess (though I am not expert in algebraic geometry) is that you can find an affine variety in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,x_3]$ of dimension one, such that you cannot generate the ideal with only functions $f$ within the constraint $v(f)\leq2$.

Comment: To throw in a random example which accords with my gut feeling but which I can't prove, how about the intersection of $x^2+y^2+z^2=2$ and $x^3+y^3+z^3=1$?